# connect azure database with c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure-sql-database

I have a database in an Azure portal that I need to access to using Visual Studio. I have already set up the data connection in server explorer, but since this is my first time using a database for C#, I have no idea on how to connect to the database.

```
 string connectionString = ConsoleApplication4.Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString;

 SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Connection_String);
```

But I'm seeing errors when attempting to connect to it. I'm trying to set the data connection that I have added but I don't know how.

Comment: Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336243.aspx

Comment: "But I'm having errors regarding it"   It might be helpful if you shared WHAT errors.  Also, I see no Open method on the database connection.  It might be helpful if you shared the COMPLETE code.

Comment: What part of the documentation that you read and tried to implement didn't work?  You've provided no detail that *anyone* could use to tell you specifics...

Comment: Do you use correct connection string? Use my favourite site http://connectionstrings.com/sql-azure. I have always found the right connection string there :)

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this, I am trying to visual studio and C# atm